# Should all Ubuntu Touch apps use a MainView?

Tags: application-development, qml, ubuntu-sdk

I know the [MainView](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/devel/ubuntu-13.10/qml/ui-toolkit/qml-ubuntu-components0-mainview.html) component is the recommended container for all widgets that are part of an Ubuntu Touch app. However, I'd like to understand whether it is essential to use it and what it brings to an app. From the documentation:

> MainView is the root Item that should be used for all applications. It
>   automatically adds a header and toolbar for its contents and can
>   rotate its content based on the device orientation.

Basically, I'd like to know exactly what features or properties MainView adds to an Ubuntu Touch app and if it's a strict requirement to use it to write convergent apps for Ubuntu.

A use case would be for an app that does not need a header.

Comment: If you don't need the header, you should just be able to set the title to an empty string (`""`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Headers and toolbars are part of the MainView, so you would have to implement that yourself if you don't use MainView.

Also the MainView has an "ActionManager" which is needed for actions from the app to become available to the HUD. Other properties that we need (for example for application switching) such as an AppID may also be added to the MainView.

So it is highly recommended to use the MainView, even if you don't use headers or toolbars. I can imagine that some special apps (games?) would not be using MainView, but then you may end up implementing functionality of MainView yourself. Of course this is possible (since MainView and all related classes are open source), but it is something that is hard for us to support.